# Stack Overflow Deleted Questions Archive

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions, archive

What are some of the more popular questions on Stack Overflow that have been deleted?

This is an archive of popular deleted questions on Stack Overflow, mostly from the days when a broader range of questions were allowed.  Also, they may be a poor question, but have really good answers.

**Related:**

- An unofficial partial archive can be found [here](http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted).
- And another site with a deleted listing is [here](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/)

**I've split these up by categories like the [Deleted Meta Questions Archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61221/13295). Please feel free to improve them as you please.**

Comment: Why not put your popular content on a blog or a wiki page somewhere? These posts were deleted for a reason; linking to them here doesn't really serve any purpose.

Comment: It's not my popular content.  And 132 votes on MSE for this question shows that it does serve a purpose.  I'm moving it here so that it is specifically on-topic.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: That type of content never worked, it's been declared off-topic, the posts are locked and rot away. Leaving them on the site gives people excuses to post more. The content is CC Wiki released, you are free to host it elsewhere. In the meantime, this post *and* the one on Meta.SE are, in my view, useless and not on-topic either.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, because it has the Programmers stuff on it also.  I was trying to insure that it would be on-topic.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, you've just turned the question into a big "screw that, gonna post it here anyway" with the answer still around. Not much of a discussion when the list is already there.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, I don't mind the discussion.  Ultimately, I just don't want to see the knowledge lost, i.e. some of those questions might help me someday learn something and there's no way to search deleted questions.

Comment: I have no problem with that set of questions remaining deleted. But I am struggling to see the great harm in having a single Meta question that points to some of the more "popular" or fun ones.

Comment: I do not dare to close that, it will increase my fail-rank.

Comment: These questions should be pulled to an external site somewhere so non-10k users can read them.

Comment: If I want to propose a question to be added to this list, how would I do that? For example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816234/log4j-2-0-vs-logback)

Comment: @durron597, that one was in my backlog, I've added it now to Tools. You're welcome to edit links into the appropriate category.

Comment: @TylerH I agree.  as of right now there are 7614 people on here that can view these post which is only 1.8% of the register users on the site.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Oh, I would have if the posts were community wiki

Comment: Hmmm, never noticed they weren't. The one I created on Meta SE is, I'll flag for that.

Comment: @Lance post is now CW

Comment: Candidate: [the "top" COBOL (and 2nd-top FORTRAN) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298835)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Programming**

- [What is Your Solution to the FizzBuzz Problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437/what-is-your-solution-to-the-fizzbuzz-problem)
- [What Is Your Most Useful SQL Trick to Avoid Writing More Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488020/what-is-your-most-useful-sql-trick-to-avoid-writing-more-code)
- [What is the Best Roulette Player Algorithm Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480482/what-is-the-best-roulette-player-algorithm-strategy)
- [What are common UI misconceptions and annoyances?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011167/13295)
- [How to Add an Existing User Into a Group in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283068/how-to-add-an-existing-user-into-a-group-in-linux)
- [Is Literate Programming Dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545136/is-literate-programming-dead)
- [Why Doesn't Oracle Support Boolean Datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518356/why-doesnt-oracle-support-boolean-datatype)
- [Continuous Integration in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722649/continuous-integration-in-nodejs)
- [How to Copy a Table Schema and Constraints to a Table of a Different Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600172/how-to-copy-a-table-schema-and-constraints-to-a-table-of-different-database)
- [Shortcut to Apply a Formula to an Entire Column in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425210/shortcut-to-apply-a-formula-to-an-entire-column-in-excel)
- [Difference between two strings in Python/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209800/difference-between-two-strings-in-python-php)
- [How Can I Prevent Users From Taking Screenshots of My Application Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455623/how-can-i-prevent-users-from-taking-screenshots-of-my-application-window)
- [How to Draw Multiple Overlapping Circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233879/how-to-draw-multiple-overlapping-circles)
- [How do You Count Your Lines of Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104756/how-do-you-count-your-lines-of-code)
- [Are There Examples where VBA Variant Variables are Useful Even Though the Data Type the Variable Will Store is Known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488314/are-there-examples-where-vba-variant-variables-are-useful-even-though-the-data-t)
- [Do You Find Convention Over Configuration Good or Bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166539/do-you-find-convention-over-configuration-good-or-bad)
- [Compare Two Lists C# LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815387/compare-two-lists-c-sharp-linq)
- [Repository Pattern Tutorial in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c-sharp)
- [How To Draw Charts in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271248/how-to-draw-charts-in-android)
- [Decode Email Address from Gravatar Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415/decode-email-address-from-gravatar-hash)
- [What is Your Preferred Syntax for SQL Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981938/what-is-your-preferred-syntax-for-sql-aliases)
- [Microsoft Internal Coding Guidelines: Don't Use Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784481/microsoft-internal-coding-guidelines-dont-use-tabs)
- [What Are Your Experiences Selling On the Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896377/what-are-your-experiences-selling-on-the-android-market)
- [CodeChef and Challenge Style Programming in the Context of My Career Growth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099853/codechef-and-challenge-style-programming-in-the-context-of-my-career-growth)
- [Reasons for rejecting iPhone Application by Apple Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308479/reasons-for-rejecting-iphone-application-by-apple-store)
- [In Bash, When Do Lines Need To Be Terminated with a Semi-Colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530110/in-bash-when-do-lines-need-to-be-terminated-with-a-semi-colon)
- [Photoshop Pt Size Conversion to Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868627/photoshop-pt-size-conversion-to-web)
- [Amazon - EC2 Cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158765/amazon-ec2-cost)
- [Accessing a Remote Form in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249/accessing-a-remote-form-in-php)
- [SEO: Relative URL vs Absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418069/seo-relative-url-vs-absolute-url)
- [JDK Not Detected, Issue During Android SDK Tools Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588548/help-jdk-not-detected-problem-during-android-sdk-tools-setup)
- [Useful Math For Programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743/useful-math-for-programmers)
- [How to Create a Text Editor in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281438/how-to-create-a-text-editor-in-jquery)
- [Why Are We Still Using Compiler Command Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100353/why-are-we-still-using-compiler-command-lines)
- [Selling Android Apps and Taxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351256/selling-android-apps-and-taxes)
- [Convert GUID to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518684/convert-guid-to-int)
- [What Makes COBOL such a Hate Language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2549399/13295)

Comment: For the records, StackPrinter has (some of?) this posts. [Example](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service=stackoverflow&question=182112).

Comment: @brasofilo, yep, that's the one under Related:

Comment: ^facepalm, that escaped from my radar, thx Lance

Comment: Candidate: [the "top" COBOL (and 2nd-top FORTRAN) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298835)

Answer (score 3):

**Humor & Programmer Idiosyncrasies**

- [What Was Your First Home Computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102714/what-was-your-first-home-computer)
- [Worst UI You've Ever Used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238177/worst-ui-youve-ever-used)
- [How Do You Clear Your Mind After a Day of Coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784461/how-do-you-clear-your-mind-after-a-day-of-coding)
- [How Do You Deal With a Program That's Become Self Aware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561112/how-to-deal-with-a-program-that-has-become-self-aware)
- [Surprise for a Programmer on Birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420689/surprise-for-a-programmer-on-birthday)
- [Programmers' Last Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469445/programmers-last-words)
- [How Can You Tell If a Person is a Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895296/how-can-you-tell-if-a-person-is-a-programmer)
- [Who in the Software World do you Admire the Most?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545/who-in-the-software-world-do-you-admire-the-most)
- [Most Astonishing Violation of the Principle of Least Astonishment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235848/most-astonishing-violation-of-the-principle-of-least-astonishment)
- [As a programmer, what are some telltale signs that you're about to get fired or laid off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443638/as-a-programmer-what-are-some-telltale-signs-that-youre-about-to-get-fired-or)
- [What is your favorite “programmer” t-shirt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192793/what-is-your-favorite-programmer-t-shirt)
- [Humor in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140270/humor-in-code)
- [What are some funny loading statements to keep users amused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182112/what-are-some-funny-loading-statements-to-keep-users-amused)
- [Most Elegant, Amusing or Strange Code One Liners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830/most-elegant-amusing-or-strange-code-one-liners)
- [Telecommuting in the programming profession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159337/telecommuting-in-the-programming-profession/395464)
- [New Programming Jargon You Coined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined)
- [Great Programming Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes)
- [Keyboard for Programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687)
- [What is the funniest bug that you've ever experienced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175854/what-is-the-funniest-bug-youve-ever-experienced/)
- [One piece of advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553/one-piece-of-advice)
- [What is the worst interview question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464/what-is-the-worst-interview-question)
- [What is the worst interviewee answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598/what-is-the-worst-interviewee-answer)
- [Computer Language puns and jokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512/computer-language-puns-and-jokes)
- [Music to listen to while coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947/music-to-listen-to-while-coding)
- [Identifying passionate programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247/identifying-passionate-programmers)
- [What are the Valuable Lessons of History in Programming and Software Engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620984/what-are-the-valuable-lessons-of-history-in-programming-and-software-engineering)
- [What's your biggest fear as a programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347190/whats-your-biggest-fear-as-a-programmer/)
- [What Is Your Best Friend As A Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700205/what-is-your-best-friend-as-a-programmer)
- [What is the Most Clever Code You've Ever Seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226469/what-is-the-most-clever-code-youve-ever-seen)
- [What is the Worst Code You've Ever Written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130965/what-is-the-worst-code-youve-ever-written)
- [Can a Programmer Become a Decent Graphic Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807/can-a-programmer-become-a-decent-graphic-designer)
- [Can You Be Terrible At Math and Still Be a Great Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529/can-you-be-terrible-at-math-and-still-a-great-programmer)
- [What Does Your Code Do To Contact You When Things Go Badly Wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868684/what-does-your-code-do-to-contact-you-when-things-go-badly-wrong)
- [What Exactly is a Software Architect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976635/what-exactly-is-a-software-architect)
- [How to Keep Concentrated and Focused While Waiting For Your Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922/how-to-keep-concentrated-and-focused-while-waiting-for-your-compiler)
- [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered)
- [What was the strangest coding standard rule that you were forced to follow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218123/what-was-the-strangest-coding-standard-rule-that-you-were-forced-to-follow)

Answer (score 2):

**Tools**

- [What is a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217758/what-is-a-rest-api)
- [Best ASP.net E-Commerce Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234/best-asp-net-e-commerce-framework)
- [Do I Really Need Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250984/do-i-really-need-version-control)
- [What PHP framework would you choose for a new application and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why)
- [What bug tracking software do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328/what-bug-tracking-software-do-you-use)
- [Essential Programming Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187/essential-programming-tools)
- [Best Open Source Project Hosting Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490/best-open-source-project-hosting-site)
- [What JavaScript library would you choose for a new project and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913/what-javascript-library-would-you-choose-for-a-new-project-and-why)
- [Most Useful Free .Net Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/662956)
- [Is There a Tool for Converting Javascript to Coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510906/is-there-a-tool-for-converting-javascript-to-coffeescript)
- [Is There a Way to View .NET Framework Library Source Code Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478852/is-there-a-way-to-view-net-framework-library-source-code-online)
- [Struts2 or JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845271/struts-2-or-jsf)
- [Best Javascript Library for Drag and Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438193/best-javascript-library-for-drag-and-drop)
- [NodeJS Cluster vs JXcore Multithread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889229/nodejs-cluster-vs-jxcore-multithread)
- [Any Good Graphing Packages for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android)
- [Good Open Source Ruby on Rails Projects to Learn From](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248371/good-open-source-ruby-on-rails-projects-to-learn-from)
- [From Java Code to UML Diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687323/from-java-code-to-uml-diagram)
- [Is There Anything Like RegexBuddy in the Open Source World](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world)
- [Text Editor For Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626203/text-editor-for-scala)
- [What's the Simplest IOC container for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515124/whats-the-simplest-ioc-container-for-c)
- [Best Free SQLlite Management Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543337/best-free-sqlite-management-tool)
- [Choosing a Web Application Framework Using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809539/choosing-a-web-application-framework-using-node-js)
- [Alternative to knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747914/alternative-to-knockout-js)
- [What Tools are Available for Documenting JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221413/what-tools-are-available-for-documenting-javascript)
- [Online C++ Compiler and Evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator)
- [Well Documented Open Source Python Projects for a Beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907561/well-documented-open-source-python-projects-for-a-beginner)
- [Where Can I Find an Online JavaScript Editor and Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814453/where-can-i-find-an-online-javascript-editor-and-console)
- [What Are Some Free and/or Open Source Requirements Management Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164938/what-are-some-free-and-or-open-source-requirements-management-tools)
- [Looking for WYSIWYG HTML editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833/looking-for-wysiwyg-html-editor)
- [Alternatives to gprof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof)
- [Watir vs Selenium vs Sahi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606550/watir-vs-selenium-vs-sahi)
- [Difference between Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358458/difference-between-visual-studio-2012-and-visual-studio-2013)
- [What C# Mocking Framework to Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use)
- [What are Some Good Unit Testing Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101/what-are-some-good-unit-testing-examples)
- [Is There a Webservice API to Grab a Screenshot of Another Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342611/is-there-a-webservice-api-to-grab-a-screenshot-of-another-website)
- [What's a Good Alternative Windows Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440269/whats-a-good-alternative-windows-console)
- [PySide vs PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297660/pyside-vs-pyqt)
- [How to Get Started with XSLt Transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594255/how-to-get-started-with-xslt-transformations)
- [Why does IntelliJ IDEA compile Scala so Slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606591/why-does-intellij-idea-compile-scala-so-slowly)
- [What Tools Can I Use to Test a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349618/what-tools-can-i-use-to-test-a-rest-api)
- [What are the Best Web Design Sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034758/what-are-the-best-web-design-sites)
- [How to Choose between Zombie.js and PhantomJS for Automated Web Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498308/how-to-choose-between-zombie-js-and-phantomjs-for-automated-web-testing)
- [Node.js Express vs Geddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683916/node-js-express-vs-geddy)
- [Open Source Alternative to Microsoft Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109579/open-source-alternative-to-microsoft-project)
- [CDN Recommendation for Modernizr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745603/cdn-recommendation-for-modernizr)
- [Best IDE for Grails/Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233664/best-ide-for-grails-groovy)
- [What is a Good OO C++ Wrapper for Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120295/what-is-a-good-oo-c-wrapper-for-sqlite)
- [What Does AngularJS do Better Than jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery)
- [IDE for Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507957/ide-for-golang)
- [Open Source Service like Parse or Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043722/open-source-service-like-parse-or-firebase)
- [What is the Best Back Button jQuery Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin)
- [Use jQuery or Q.js for Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610741/use-jquery-or-q-js-for-promises)
- [C++ Logging Library Recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084052/c-logging-library-recommendation)
- [What is the Best Choice for Building Windows Installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers)
- [Java Swing or Java Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422956/java-swing-or-java-qt)
- [Is Qt Worth Learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604917/is-qt-worth-learning)
- [Qt vs WPF/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800219/qt-versus-wpf-net)
- [Spring MVC or Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189115/spring-mvc-or-grails)
- [Best Flowchart Software (Online or Offline, Preferrably Free)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705476/best-flowchart-software-online-or-offline-preferrably-free)
- [KnockoutJS Unit Testing with Qunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331789/knockoutjs-unit-testing-with-qunit)
- [Tools for Generating UML Class Diagram from C# Source or DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600802/tools-for-generating-uml-class-diagram-from-c-sharp-source-or-dll)
- [Hex Editor for Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160405/hex-editor-for-mac-osx)
- [What is Pro and Contra of Using Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376732/what-is-pro-and-contra-of-using-play-framework)
- [Is There Any Free AST Diff Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829453/is-there-any-free-ast-diff-tool)
- [Best IDE for Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91445/best-ide-for-ruby-on-rails)
- [What is the Best CSS Grid Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996/what-is-the-best-css-grid-framework)
- [What is the Best Image Manipulation Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158756/what-is-the-best-image-manipulation-library)
- [Online Peer Code Review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542/online-peer-code-review)
- [What is the Best Rails Example App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457087/what-is-the-best-rails-example-app)
- [Assembla is No Longer Free, is There A Good Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233219/assembla-is-no-longer-free-is-there-a-good-alternative)
- [What Open Source Hosting Service Should I Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736/what-open-source-hosting-service-should-i-use)
- [Is There a Free Version Control Server Provider for Non-Public Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430742/is-there-a-free-version-control-server-provider-for-non-public-projects)
- [Simple HTTP Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530787/simple-http-web-server)
- [Windows GUI Tool for Enabling/Disabling Hosts File Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800479/windows-gui-tool-for-enabling-disabling-hosts-file-entries)
- [Elasticsearch as a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636508/elasticsearch-as-a-database)
- [Anyone Know of an NFL or NBA API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57106/anyone-know-of-an-nfl-or-nba-api)
- [Basic Differences between Oracle and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322260/basic-differences-between-oracle-and-sql-server)
- [Which Tool do you Suggest, to Convert a Legacy Delphi 7.0 App to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507839/which-tool-do-you-suggest-to-convert-a-legacy-delphi-7-0-app-to-c-sharp)
- [Python Web Frameworks, an Honest Opinion Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976649/python-web-frameworks-an-honest-opinion-required)
- [Revisiting the issue of LWJGL vs JOGL for Game Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644872/revisiting-the-issue-of-lwjgl-vs-jogl-for-game-programming)
- [Good IDE/editor for C++ Suited to my Tastes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754020/good-ide-editor-for-c-suited-to-my-tastes)
- [Which File Comparison Tool Can Handle Block Movement and Multiple Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96051/which-file-comparison-tool-can-handle-block-movement-and-multiple-revisions)
- [Tools for Automated GUI Testing (on Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120359/tools-for-automated-gui-testing-on-windows)
- [Heroku in Real Life Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075920/heroku-in-real-life-apps)
- [Distributed Source Control Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237/distributed-source-control-options)
- [What Off-the-Shelf Licensing System will Meet My Needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889902/what-off-the-shelf-licensing-system-will-meet-my-needs)
- [Complete, Monospaced Unicode Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586503/complete-monospaced-unicode-font)
- [Tool for Automated Testing Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632934/tool-for-automated-testing-web-application)
- [How is a Git Soft Reset Supposed to Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598374/how-is-a-git-soft-reset-supposed-to-work)
- [Why Aren't People Using the CSS Flexbox Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094887/why-arent-people-using-the-css-flexbox-module)
- [PHPmyadmin Is Not Working After I Installed It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893799/phpmyadmin-is-not-working-after-i-installed-it)
- [Log4j 2.0 vs. Logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816234/log4j-2-0-vs-logback)

Answer (score 2):

**Languages**

- [What Are Five Things You Hate About Your Favorite Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/282329/13295)
- [Erlang vs Go vs Rust Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339560/erlang-versus-go-versus-rust-comparison)
- [What's Wrong with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731/whats-wrong-with-c)
- [Learning Scala or Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805429/learning-scala-or-haskell)
- [Yet Another Haskell vs Scala Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820801/yet-another-haskell-vs-scala-question)
- [Alternatives to Java for Android Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419556/alternatives-to-java-for-android-development)
- [Is Python Any Good for GUI Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development)
- [Differences Between C++ and C#/.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291513/differences-between-c-and-c-net)
- [Have You Actually Convinced Anybody to SCALA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674081/have-you-actually-convinced-anybody-to-scala)
- [What are the Major Differences Between Ruby 1.9.3 and Ruby 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799687/what-are-the-major-differences-between-ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-2-0-0)
- [What Can Lisp Do That Lua Can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323346/what-can-lisp-do-that-lua-cant)
- [PHP vs Python Scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588617/php-vs-python-scalability)
- [Is Haskell a Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696618/is-haskell-a-lisp)
- [Learning an Additional Functional Language: Clojure vs. Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765037/learning-an-additional-functional-language-clojure-vs-erlang)
- [Is R "that bad" That It Should be Rewritten From Scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706990/is-r-that-bad-that-it-should-be-rewritten-from-scratch)
- [Clojure vs Haskell for Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355314/clojure-vs-haskell-for-web-applications)
- [What Advantages Does Modern Fortran Have Over Modern C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821913/what-advantages-does-modern-fortran-have-over-modern-c)
- [Why Do Java Programmers Love Scala and Shy Away from Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346804/why-do-java-programmers-love-scala-and-shy-away-from-clojure)
- [What Functional Programming Language Should I Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744368/which-functional-programming-language-should-i-use)
- [Web Development: Haskell or Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796350/web-development-haskell-or-scheme)
- [What are the Main Differences of Language Features between Haskell and the Functional part of F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541487/what-are-the-main-differences-of-language-features-between-haskell-and-the-funct)
- [Is Clojure or Haskell better for Making Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997003/is-clojure-or-haskell-better-for-making-command-line-tools)
- [ASP.NET vs C# (comparison)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642654/asp-net-vs-c-sharp-comparison)
- [Design Patterns, A New Criterion for Comparing Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594205/design-patterns-a-new-criterion-for-comparing-languages)
- [What Are PHP's Advantages over Ruby on Rails and Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821524/what-are-phps-advantages-over-ruby-on-rails-and-django)
- [Why is C++ Relatively "harder" to Use/Bad Choice for a Beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085134/why-is-c-relatively-harder-to-use-bad-choice-for-a-beginner)
- [What Defines Pythonian or Pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58968/what-defines-pythonian-or-pythonic)
- [What Are the things Java got Wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457884/what-are-the-things-java-got-wrong)
- [Do You Say No to C# Regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755465/do-you-say-no-to-c-sharp-regions)
- [The Zen of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228181/the-zen-of-python)
- [Why Does Java Have the Reputation of Being Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163411/why-did-java-have-the-reputation-of-being-slow)
- [What Do These New C# 6 Features Do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881465/what-do-these-new-c-sharp-6-features-do)
- [Is C++ Worth Investing Time in Learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151894/is-c-worth-investing-time-in-learning)
- [(For what) Are Fortran, Cobol and Co. used today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266643/for-what-are-fortran-cobol-and-co-used-today)

Answer (score 2):

**Tutorials & Resources**

- [What Programming Book Would You NOT Recommend to Developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184118/what-programming-book-would-you-not-recommend-to-developers)
- [PHP Tutorial that is Security Accuracy and Maintainability-Conscious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious)
- [Any Good Tutorial for Mongoose with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319899/any-good-tutorial-for-mongoose-with-node-js)
- [Python JSON Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759634/python-json-tutorial)
- [Best Objective-C Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645050/best-objective-c-tutorial)
- [GO language tutorials or books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549198/go-language-tutorials-or-books)
- [Which Tutorial on Clojure is Best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599519/which-tutorial-on-clojure-is-best)
- [Getting Started with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239917/getting-started-with-opengl)
- [Where Can I Find a Good Tutorial on OpenGL using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279924/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-opengl-using-java)
- [Tutorials For Caliburn Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281534/tutorials-for-caliburn-framework)
- [The Best CSS Tutorial/Site/Blog/Book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132587/the-best-css-tutorial-site-blog-book)

Answer (score 1):

**Best Practices & Tips**

- [Biggest Performance Improvement You've Had With The Smallest Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545844/biggest-performance-improvement-youve-had-with-the-smallest-change)
- [What CSS tips should every beginning developer know about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500827/what-css-tips-should-every-beginning-developer-know-about) - [deletion discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173549/four-year-old-question-with-48-upvotes-and-81-stars-just-got-deleted) - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVKxF.png)
- [What are some good tips for a new PHP developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285700/what-are-some-good-tips-for-a-new-php-developer)
- [Best practice for CSS reset style sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/best-practice-for-css-reset-style-sheet)
- [SOLID principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423597/solid-principles)
- [Best Practices in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193298/best-practices-in-latex)
- [What Are the Top CSS Gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047254/what-are-the-top-css-gotchas) - [deletion discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173549/four-year-old-question-with-48-upvotes-and-81-stars-just-got-deleted)
- [Netbeans Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628830/netbeans-tips-and-tricks)
- [How Should I get Started with Android Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256/how-should-i-get-started-with-android-development)