# Why is question deletion a lesser privilege than answer deletion?

Tags: discussion, privileges, vote-to-delete

When a question is deleted, so are the answers. It's called *"question deletion"* but it's actually *"question and answer deletion"*.

Shouldn't it be the other way around? 10k gets to delete LQ answers, 20k gets to nuke entire Q&A's.

Question deletion has also been recently shown to have the potential to spur quite a bit of controversy, most of which actually surrounded the deletion of *answers* on those questions, not *questions* per se.

I just had this thought randomly, and now I can't wrap my head around it.

Why is question deletion a lesser privilege when it deletes *more* content, *including answers*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can't just vote to delete *any* question.

Questions must be closed before non-mods can cast delete votes. And if reopened, any pending delete votes are instantly removed. This adds a second level of oversight to the process.

Answers don't have this protection; the only requirement for deleting an answer is that it score < 0.

Note that there are other differences as well... For instance, answers deleted by their authors can't just be undeleted by 20k users, unlike questions, where it is assumed that others have contributed and the Q&A thread is no longer a single author's work.

#### see also: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: *"you can't just vote to delete any question"* But I can delete **answers** with 100+ upvotes.

Comment: Only if you're deleting the question, and then it takes more votes from others. Or, I guess, if you *wrote* the answer (but only if it wasn't accepted).

Comment: Okay, but that's really an arbitrary restriction. Answer deletion could easily require more votes. I'm looking for some reasoning. Why do we get to delete more stuff earlier? Unless you are saying less oversight for the 20k privilege *is* the reasoning.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The 20k privilege was added after the 10k privilege, if that helps.

Comment: @Radiodef If the question got closed (and remained closed), the answers probably shouldn't have been posted in the first place. We close questions that are either unanswerable or outside the community's expertise. In general, answers to those questions are rarely valuable, regardless of their upvotes.

Comment: @Yannis Not necessarily according to this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/2891664

Comment: That question was asked in 2008 @Radiodef, it's not a good example of... anything, really. If it had been asked today, it would be closed almost instantly and probably wouldn't have had the chance to gather answers. Also, it's not a perfect system, and there will always be exceptions. But it's good enough, and it works - in general.

Comment: @Yannis Lots of questions like that have been deleted (as a minority, but nevertheless). http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256639/2891664 Point is, a question being closed doesn't invalidate the usefulness of its answers.

Comment: I somehow doubt there was anything of real value lost when "Computer Language puns and jokes" or "Who in the software world do you admire the most?" were deleted @Radiodef...

Comment: @Yannis ...Did you actually read the list? They're off-topic but most of them **aren't** jokes.

Comment: Honestly, I don't have time to scan through lists to find questions that support your arguments @Radiodef. If you want to convince anyone that the system is fundamentally broken, then I'd suggest you update your question here to include actual examples of valueable answers that were lost because of what you think is an imbalance in the deletion privileges (i.e. wouldn't have been lost of the privileges were the other way around).

Comment: @Yannis *"If you want to convince anyone that the system is fundamentally broken"* Or maybe I just think it could be better. *"include actual examples of valueable answers that were lost"* You're making the assumption that I believe such answers exist.