# Another old, off-topic, popular question - can it be deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, clean-up

I've previously approached this here with this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297684/1927206

The question I linked-to there, the "top" COBOL (and 2nd-top FORTRAN) question, is now gone. Thanks to those involved in however that happened.

I'm kicking off with the next one to try to connect to something Tim Post is looking at: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298810/1927206

My intention is to get the COBOL tag cleansed of material which brings no value. My hope is that some day all tags can be cleansed in an efficient and acceptable way.

So, for now, manually: [What makes COBOL such a hated language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2549399/1927206)

63 votes, 14 favourites, 15,427 views, five years old, 17 answers, currently closed. Top answer has 54 votes (net) followed by 39 and 27.

Today the question would be off-topic for SO (chose from several reasons). Does it have content for which it deserves to exist, no matter that?

The OP cannot even be clear about whether COBOL is still in use or not. Several humorous (your mileage may vary) references may indicate that the question is at least in part tongue-in-cheek. It is a "this has a question-mark so it is a question" question. The benefit of the question existing on SO is missing for me.

## What about the answers?

To start with, with all the off-topicness in the question, good answers would be incredibly difficult to produce. So, rather than attempting to judge them by the question, do they contain material which is 1) worth retaining and 2) will be found by search-enginers?

Nope. I can't do that. Although there may be worthwhile nuggets in there (I doubt it), the answers are opinion, of varying quality, much of it fallacy or simply outdated.

If the whole lot were to be deleted, no-one would miss it, and no-one would ever (substantially in one post) duplicate any of the material in any of the answers in a future SO question.

## Can the whole lot be deleted?

And, the link to Tim Post's thing, how to generalise this process (removing off-topic questions with their answers where there is no redeeming value), is the "deprecating" of accepted/non-accepted previously awesome answers which have aged to better-target the more useful material which has superseded the original answers. The deprecating of non-awesomeness is surely deletion.

Comment: Bill, I had an answer on that question that I would like to refer back to. Is there a copy of this question anywhere that I can get hold of?

Comment: Although the question didn't meet SO guidelines, I thought it had some good information in there. There were even a few laughs! :)

Comment: Never mind, I've found it on the Internet Archive

Comment: Thing is, you'd be the only person able to find your answer, and the only person able to know what use to make of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, someone has gone and done it. [The question is KAPUT!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0sEzNQtzaE)