# Some more old questions which are have no value

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer, old-questions, old-answers

Following on from this one, [Another old, off-topic, popular question - can it be deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298835/1927206) this will (may) be the last current attempt to do some cleansing manually.

I suspect there are 20-30 of these for the COBOL tag, so I'm wary of bringing them all up individually.

Listing the whole bunch would be asking too much of Meta users.

So if there is going to be some new type of queue soon, fed by tag-trusted users, there may be an opportunity to get a mechanism by which these types of questions (off-topic today, no value in answers) can be routinely directed toward the shredder and including the possibility of rescuing the accidental or borderline use.

In the light of that, here a bunc... here's three questions that differ slightly in type from those two already deleted "manually" through individual questions here:

1. [What's this language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2342328/1927206). Old, eight score (high for the tag) votes, low views, five answers, scoring 15, five and five for the top three.

The OP only sought an answer out of interest. The times that a language recently in use at a site needs to be identified must be severely limited. Poking the first line of code into a search engine will provide the basic answer.

Question has been viewed 434 times in five years. No answerer spotted that the code will not compile, or that it is a specific dialect of COBOL which supports a 78-level constant defintion (that plus another hint point towards it likely being a Micro Focus COBOL). However, given the intent of the asker, an actual detailed answer would not have been (any more) useful, and the answers provided have been little use to anyone at all over the years.

2.https://stackoverflow.com/q/731960/1927206, a tool recommendation. A "split" question, with vital information in the title which is not repeated in the body. Six years old. Popular, with 10,542 views. Scoring three, and with eight answers, four, two and one being the top three scores.

Apart from one user, no-one read the body of the question and just tossed in some irrelevant rubbish (IBM Enterprise COBOL programs will be running on an IBM Mainframe, and any "Eclipse plugin" would require full support for the environment that would be used for execution. Both IBM and Micro Focus supply paid-for products which are full IDEs, no one provides "plugins" to do this).

One user provided two answers. The first correctly identifying the name of the IBM product at the time. Their second post effectively advertises plugins for that product. (Please don't flag that as "spam", remember how old the post is, and also if you look into that user's profile, and search on Meta you'll see they have already taken beatings for various other posts).

If a searcher is looking for a COBOL-usable plug-in, they may be put off on locating the question (they are no using IBM Enterprise COBOL), the other "try this" answers are likely not up-to-date (and likely will never be updated) and information can be found by search-engining. It does not need to be on SO, and is unlikely to provide useful content to a future searcher.

The question could be re-written to make the answers more applicable (delete the existing body and copy the title to the body would be a starting point) but you still end up with a "recommendation" question anyway.

3. [Which language would you port COBOL programs to and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/771136/1927206). Opinion. Six years old. 845 views. Question-score of five, eight answers, five, three and two scored.

A question addressed to each individual, individually, who reads it.

The lack of context in the question sums up the answers: "unless you specifically *need* to replace the COBOL for a *genuine* reason you're probably better off leaving it alone and augmenting it externally".

There are some good conversational responses (and some rubbish) but SO is not the place (outside of ephemeral comments) for conversational responses, good or bad.

---

So, can this bunc... these three be deleted?

I've been wondering if there is sufficient stuff in other tags to provide some "automation" for the process. I suspect there is, and I've found some support for that by looking at the holders of the Reversal badge on SO. It should perhaps not be surprising, but more than half of the questions (and therefore the answers) are not available (subject to reputation level) for the Reversal badge.

I'm going to poke up some dummy answers to gauge response to this idea, suggesting an upvote for the answer closest to how you feel about it. I didn't think of downvotes, so... just use one if you particularly object, perhaps.

Comment: Firstly do I don't understand why we need to have this argument again.

Comment: Secondly, this can't work as most people's votes will be reversed because of the way you've set it up: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150180/the-vote-fraud-script-breaks-legitimate-polling-questions-a-serial-downvoter

Comment: @Ben have you got a link for the again? Are you talking about my three posts here?

Comment: @Ben to be honest, I was expecting one upvote for people's preferred answers. Not one upvote and then some downvotes on the other answers.

Comment: Reminds me of a Sunday morning, many years ago.  The doorbell rings, a strapping young fellow hands me a clipboard and asks: "I'm running a petition against industrial pollution, do you want to sign it?".  Erm, wait, how many people refused to sign because they *favor* pollution?  He noodled for a while, turned out his real intention was to sell me a magazine subscription.  What are you selling?

Comment: @HansPassant Magazine subscriptions. Three-month free trial, but you have to give me your bank details upfront and make sure you cancel in time before the fourth month (actual point in time for cancellation deliberately left vague). Reminds me of a joke magazine advert. Advertisement with two boxes, first says "Yes, rush me my special offer at an initial cost of £49.99", second says, "No thanks, I'm a paedophile"

Answer (score 1):

Leave them. Content is content. Search-enginers can evaluate their worth.

Answer (score 1):

Delete them. We want the best content for programming-related questions, and keeping content of highly-questionable use waters down that idea.

Comment: I would normally say flag them but it they don't get much response In my opinion I would say delete them would be best if the questions are generally low quality, off topic etc.

Comment: off topic questions need to be deleted, otherwise they just serve as examples that off topic questions are really not off topic because you get answers

Answer (score 1):

Who are you to decide anything like that. Flag it and move on, but don't expect much response, as "domain-knowledge" cannot be something we rely on finding amongst flag-handlers.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above. Forget it and move on.