# How to find those old gems on SO?

Tags: support, search, historical-lock

There are some entertaining Q&As from the early years of Stack Overflow which are no longer on‑topic, such as:

- [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184618/1115360)
- [What was the strangest coding standard rule that you were forced to follow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218123/1115360)

They are now:

> **Locked.** This question and its answers are locked because the question is off-topic but has historical significance. It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions.

There are no questions tagged [historical-lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/historical-lock), and [locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locked) is for other things.

Is there any way to find them other than serendipitously?

Comment: There is a large list in the answers to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256638/stack-overflow-deleted-questions-archive

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That's a great find! Do you think those questions should be tagged "historical-lock"? That tag exists on meta, where its purpose is for the discussion of historical locks, but not on main where perhaps it could be for questions with a historical lock. (How to get mods to hate you because only they have the power to do that tagging :( )

Comment: Meta tagging is pretty pointless. You can generally just `locked:yes is:q` or whatever (see the search guide - please don't take my word for it on the exact name, I don't remember, haven't tested, and haven't checked), and sort by votes. It'll give you a relatively big number of questions, but it's a haystack that isn't 10+ million questions, so it's a start

Comment: @Zoe Because almost all locks *except* for historical significance expire, you can add a date filter to that query to filter out, say, anything younger than 1 year & get a pretty good list. E.g. `locked:yes is:q created:..1y` will return all locked Qs which were asked at least 1 year ago or older. Questions locked for dispute will almost surely have had those locks expired (or about to expire, if they were locked for 365 days). The created filter also lets you easily choose older periods like 5y or even more complex like `..1y2m` for 1 year and 2 months ago. Move the `..` to invert the filter.

Comment: The boat programming question was hard-deleted, but it [lives on](http://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/) (referenced at 1 h 02 min 43 secs in [episode 50 of the Stack Overflow podcast](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-28), classic series (2009-04-21)).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1431286) that lists all Posts with a historical lock Postnotice.

The Postnotices table isn't sanitized for deleted posts so you can even find links to the old gems that are no longer visible. With 10K you're  able to view those questions and their answers.

```sql
select distinct
       concat(
         'site://q/'
       , postid
       , '|'
       , case 
         when p.deletiondate is not null 
         then concat('deleted (tags:', tags, ')') 
         else title
         end
      ) [Locked Link]
      , p.creationdate
      , p.score
      , p.answercount
      , p.deletiondate
from postnotices pn
inner join postswithdeleted p on p.id = pn.postid 
where postnoticetypeid = 22 -- hist lock
```

When run today  this is the result (notice that for deleted posts it shows the last known tags):

[image: links to locked posts, creationdate, score, answercount, deletiondate]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the magnificent [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: You beat me! I put basically [the same query together](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1393013/currently-historically-locked-posts) a few months ago. I was really surprised I couldn’t find one that already existed, this is a list with some fun entries.

Answer (score 11):

You can find these posts on the [annotated posts page](https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=locked&filter=noticed) using the Noticed filter of the Locked tab.

---

You will find other posts in this list, such as those with the notice:

> There are disputes about this question’s content being resolved at this time. It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions.

But they're limited in count and most of them are of the historical-significance kind. The other filters show other kinds of post notice.

Comment: Upvoted; I'm waiting for any other also-useful answers. How did you find the annotated posts page?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I stumbled across it on the [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76569/684990) some years ago

Comment: Never seen that path in any of the site nav. Is it primarily intended for admin use?

Comment: @Nick I hope [the leopard](https://whatsthepont.blog/2011/09/01/beware-of-the-leopard-vogon-planning-revisited/) (HHGTTG) didn't give you any trouble!